# Regex HTTP Request

Tags: php, c++

I used a C++ application to make a HTTP Request hence, I am trying to make a Regex Filter for a simple string to filter values.
String looks like this

```
Data : /test/freeze.php?&ip=127.0.0.1&pcname=Ganix&buf=John Oswald
```

I want it to Filter only the IP address from the expression using php Regex.

Comment: How is that received by PHP? If its a GET query string or POST body there are built ins to parse it methods ...

Comment: I think he has this as a string and wants to parse it.. `'String looks like this'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex pattern would be `ip=(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})`

PHP Example:

```
$string = "Data : /test/freeze.php?&ip=127.0.0.1&pcname=Ganix&buf=John Oswald";

preg_match('/ip=(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/', $string, $matches);

echo "IP: " . $matches[1];
```

Output: `IP: 127.0.0.1`

https://eval.in/820903

Comment: You made my Day! :) Thank you very Much!